Pagination of distinct records from the stored procedure using offset
I have two tables and columns as below
Product : Id, Name
Order : Id, ProductId, Name, CreatedDate

Now I want to do pagination of unique Product Id records.
Select P.Id As ProductId, P.Name As ProductName, O.Id As OrderId, O.Name As OrderName 
from Product P inner join O on P.Id = O.ProductId
ORDER BY P.Id    
OFFSET 0 ROWS    
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY

Above query return result like below
ProductId | ProductName | OrderId | OrderName 

100       | ProductA    | 1001    | OrderA
100       | ProductA    | 1002    | OrderB
101       | ProductB    | 1011    | OrderC
101       | ProductB    | 1012    | OrderD
101       | ProductB    | 1013    | OrderE

this query not returning unique 5 productid records
I want result something like below which return 5 distinct product id on pagination
ProductId | ProductName | OrderId | OrderName 

100       | ProductA    | 1001    | OrderA
100       | ProductA    | 1002    | OrderB
101       | ProductB    | 1011    | OrderC
101       | ProductB    | 1012    | OrderD
101       | ProductB    | 1013    | OrderE
102       | ProductC    | 1021    | OrderF
103       | ProductD    | 1031    | OrderG
104       | ProductE    | 1041    | OrderH

I have tried to using Rownumber(), Rank() and Dense_Rank() but its not returning the expected result.
How can i get distinct records using pagination offset?

First get a list of the 5 distinct products using OFFSET, then join those to your orders

DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ProductID) should give you the counter you want, and then you can do your selection on it in subquery. and remove the FETCH OFFSET thingy. It won't be fast though, but neither is OFFSET/FETCH

@siggemannen but this will return all records , i dont want to return all as it will take time to return the result. Based on pagesize limit , query has to return the result

Perhaps this pseudo code make things more clear: select * from (select *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ProductID) as rnk from yourtable) x where rnk between 1 and 5

@siggemannen :  thanks for the code and suggestion
select *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ProductID) as rnk from yourtable - But this query will return all records right, incase if i have 100000 records then it will return everything after that in subquery based on rank we are getting records

Yeah, that's why you have a WHERE that only returns the rows in your "page"

Check this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/3edBguGo

A solution with DENSE_RANK is given in the comments...
Here's a solution with OFFSET
SELECT 
        P.Id AS ProductId,
        P.Name AS ProductName,
        O.Id AS OrderId,
        O.Name AS OrderName
FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM [Product]
        ORDER BY Id OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
     ) AS P
INNER JOIN [Order] AS O
    ON P.Id = O.ProductId;

